# Помогите организовать код

Tags: javascript, ооп, рефакторинг

Есть задача получить данные о человеке и высчитать дни до др с помощью классов и конструкторов используя гет, сет.

```
class Persona {

  constructor(first, last, day, month, year) {
    this.name = {
      first,
      last
    };
    this.Birthday = {
      day,
      month,
      year
    };
  }

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`;
  }
}

var person1 = new Persona('Name', 'Surname', 11, 11, 1111);
console.log(person1.fullName);
```

Не закончил код, так как не пойму как высчитать правильно, вот нашел функцию, что по идее это делает.

```
  function daysLeft() { 

  var year = parseInt(prompt('enter year (format: YYYY)'));
  var month = parseInt(prompt('enter month (format: M)'));
  var day = parseInt(prompt('enter day')); 

  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var nextDate = new Date([today.getFullYear(),month,day].join(',')); 
  if (nextDate < today) nextDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear()+1);

  msPerDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
  daysLeft = Math.round((nextDate.getTime() - today.getTime())/msPerDay);
  dayname = "";
  ds = ""+daysLeft;

  dd=parseInt(ds.substr(ds.length-1));
    } 
  }
```

помогите плиз правильно все записать

Comment: в английском сообществе есть код ревью, попрубуй там задать вопрос - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @spectre_it [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/186999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял вам нужно вот это:

```
class Persona {
    constructor(first, last, day, month, year) {
        this.name = {
            first,
            last
        };
        this.Birthday = {
            day,
            month,
            year
        };
    }

    get fullName() {
        return `${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}`;
    }

    get daysToBirthday() {
        const today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        const nextDate = new Date([today.getFullYear(), this.Birthday.month, this.Birthday.day].join(','));
        if (nextDate < today) {
            nextDate.setFullYear(today.getFullYear() + 1);
        }
        const msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return Math.round((nextDate.getTime() - today.getTime()) / msPerDay) - 1;
    }
}

const person1 = new Persona('Name', 'Surname', 31, 12, 1990);
console.log(person1.fullName);
console.log(person1.daysToBirthday)
```